# Fire Javascript during CSS/JS animation (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit: this is an example of what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVzOjW
(Note that the menu and nav don't perfectly align, as the nav transition is being controlled by the CSS, and the menu delay is being controlled by the JS.)

I'm trying to create a slideout menu that fires some JS during the slide animation.

On page load, `nav` is fixed hidden to the right of the viewport and `menu` is fixed to the top right of the viewport. `nav` is wider than `menu`. On `menu` click fires the slideout animation of `nav`. I want to add a namespace class to `nav` that changes the `CSS` properties of `menu`. I want to do this the moment the visible portion of the `nav` becomes equal in width to the width of the `menu`, at which point the `menu` will just become part of the nav for the rest of the slideout.

I need to do this with some combination of `CSS3` and `vanilla JS` (jQuery is unavailable). I can do the `nav` animation with `CSS or JS` easy enough, but timing the CSS property changes on `menu` is what I can't figure out.

I've tried to write a loop that constantly evaluates the right property value of `nav` to see `if it's >= the width of menu` (using CSS to do the transition), but that seems to fire the entire loop right away.

I'm not picky over a CSS vs JS solution for the animation itself, but I'd prefer CSS as I feel it's easier to control the transition settings and it runs smoother.

Relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <a id="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
  <a href="#">Foo</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

#nav.expanded-nav {
  right: 0;
}

#nav.expanded-menu #menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **CSS animation chaining** or `animation-delay` or simple `setTimeout` of Vanilla JavaScript

Check out the below code for CSS way..

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
        $(".container").addClass("demo");
});
```

```css
.container {position: relative;}

#nav, #menu {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
    position: absolute;
}

#nav {
  top: 10px;
  left:-100px;
  background: #000;
  }
#menu {
  top: 150px;
  left:200px;
  background: #f00;
  }
    
.demo #nav {
    -webkit-animation: demo 1s, demo1 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}  

.demo #menu {
    -webkit-animation: demo1 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}  

@-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
        left: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 200px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo1 {
    0% {
        left: 200px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Go</button>
<div class="container">
    <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Pratik! Really appreciate your response.

So you're saying I effectively need to have 2 animations here? That might be a possible solution, but I feel like this should be able to be done with just one animation. I don't think I really need to animate menu separately from nav, I just need to change the properties on it.

The main reason I'm against the double animation is that I want this to look like one seamless animation on the nav. If I use an easing timing function, it would be hard to get both animations to match.

Comment: In that case you should try animating the parent div containing you nav and menu. That's the only solution I can think of right now. And about the easing you can use the CSS key frames to create the same effect!

Comment: Well that's the problem I'm having. I'm trying to trigger adding a class during the animation on the parent div that will update the menu child. But I can't do that with key frames. I need some JS to do that.

Comment: Pratik, I added a CodePen example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVzOjW

(Note that the menu and nav don't perfectly align, as the nav transition is being controlled by the CSS, and the menu delay is being controlled by the JS.)

Comment: Hi @Rob I have fixed your CodePen check this out http://codepen.io/pratik_shah/pen/zGpRwE (using transition) and http://codepen.io/pratik_shah/pen/wapyja (using CSS animation key-frames)

Answer (score 0):

This was actually way easier than I initially thought. It can actually rather easily be solved by setting a min-width on `menu` and allowing it to "grow" to the full length of the parent `nav' when it slides out. Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjobEJ